# How to make a div element stick to another one?

Tags: html, css

I made a box with div elements and wanted to put a navbar exactly above it. I want the navbar to be stuck to the div box, so when the page is resized they still stay together. I tried to do it manually by adjusting the navbars position with the "top" and "left" properties. But after resizing the page I realized that it wouldn't work.

Here is where I got to, my code isn't the best written since I'm quite new to CSS in general. I have added a background image and blurred it, and made the aforementioned div box.

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("Background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.asdf {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.asd {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#Box {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.Bigbox {
  font-weight: 500;
  Font-family: Helvetica;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: translate(0, -30%);
}

.text {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#image1 {
  border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  width: 500px;
  Height: 300px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <Title> title </Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>

<body class="asdf">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="asd">
      <div>
        <UL>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </UL>
      </div>
      <div id="Box" class="Bigbox">
        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum </div>
        <div class="text"> lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Images for clarification:

How it is:

[image: How it is]

How I want it to be:

[image: How I want it to be]

Comment: Can you elaborate on this `I want the navbar to be stuck to the div box, so when the page is resized they still stay together`? Maybe share a design or screenshot of how it should look like.

Comment: you want `#box` and header to be together right ? but you have made box `absolute` with `top: 50%`, `left: 50%` and also `transform: ...`

Comment: @Samir  I made some bad designs in paint but I hope they can paint a better picture. I shall add them to the post.

Comment: maybe using *margin-left* and *margin-top* is a good idear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way to do this is with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You'd make the parent element of your navbar and inner box a flex container, then apply justification and alignment rules to center its child elements.

Elements "stick" to each other by default unless you do something to change that. They're just a stack, after all.

Absolute [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is often problematic because it takes elements outside of the normal document flow. Don't use it unless you have a good understanding of why you need it.

Floats are also troublesome and not considered a modern layout technique except for a few specific cases. Avoid them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-image: url("Background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-inner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

#Box {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.Bigbox {
  font-weight: 500;
  Font-family: Helvetica;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: translate(0, -30%);
}

.text {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#image1 {
  border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  width: 500px;
  Height: 300px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <Title> title </Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <div>
        <UL>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </UL>
      </div>
      
      <div id="Box" class="Bigbox">
        <div class="title">Lorem ipsum </div>
        <div class="text"> lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```